# Checking array item convert from jsonPath to JUnit hamcrest matcher

Tags: java, junit, jsonpath, hamcrest

Hardly trying to check that json has array with two items:

```
{
  "sections" : [
    {
      "name" : "A",
      "description" : "aaa"
    },
    {
      "name" : "B",
      "description" : "bbb"
    }
  ]
}
```

But only came with

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.sections[?(@.name=='A' && @.description=='aaa')]", hasSize(1)))
```

Any way to convert this to Harmcrest matchers with hasItem/hasProperty/containInAnyOrder ?

Answer (score 0):

I think de-serializing the Json array to a list of `Section` objects will be easy to use Hamcrest Matchers. You have to override the `equals()` method in order to check whether `Section` object is available in the created `Section` list.

Section.java

```
public class Section {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Section(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final Section other = (Section) obj;
        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!this.description.equals(other.description)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use any Hamcrest Matcher you prefer.

```
RestAssured.baseURI="https://run.mocky.io/v3/bc929050-35ba-42a1-86b1-58f3fd1ead83";

List<Section> sections =  RestAssured.given()
        .when()
        .get()
        .then()
        .extract().jsonPath().getList("sections", Section.class);

Section sectionA = new Section("A", "aaa");
Section sectionB = new Section("B", "bbb");

List<Section> sectionList = new ArrayList<>();
sectionList.add(sectionA);
sectionList.add(sectionB);

assertThat(sections, hasItem(sectionA)); // pass
assertThat(sections, hasSize(2)); // pass
assertThat(sections, hasItem(hasProperty("name", equalTo("B")))); // pass
assertThat(sections, equalTo(sectionList)); // pass
assertThat(sections, containsInAnyOrder(sectionList.toArray())); // pass
```